# LINQ to XML return second element

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to return to the second <link> element in the XML from Flickr.

This always returns the first element:

```
ImageUrl = item.Element(ns + "link").Attribute("href").Value,
```

And this fails?

```
ImageUrl = item.Elements(ns + "link")[1].Attribute("href").Value,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.Skip(1).First().Attribute....` on the second snippet.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) Element returns the first matching child - Elements returns all matching children. To get the second just skip the first item and take the next one.

```
ImageUrl = item.Elements(ns + "link").Skip(1).First().Attribute("href").Value;
```

If you can't be certain there are two children you could do this:

```
XElement xe = item.Elements(ns + "link").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
if(xe != null)
{
    ImageUrl = ex.Attribute("href").Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ElementAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) to get the element at a specified position in an enumerable:

```
imageUrl = (string)item.Elements(ns + "link").ElementAt(1).Attribute("href");
```